# Похожие или сочетаемые шрифты

Tags: css, шрифты, веб-дизайн, дизайн, web-fonts

Делаю страницу по аналогии с https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/noutbuki/?sorting=price_asc&f=discount.any%2Crating.any

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю сайт по аналогии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите какие шрифты в карточке товара для моего сайта подходят, чтобы выглядело сочетаемо (какие-то похожие шрифты с теми, что использованы на ситилинке или другие, но подходящие по дизайну).

Comment: Рекомендую sans-serif. Идеальный шрифт

Comment: Подтягивайтесь все кто может - очень нужна помощь. С дизайном у меня очень плохо.

Comment: Почему меня минусуют? Нормальный вопрос.

Comment: @МегаАдыгея во-первых, субъективный, во-вторых, не про программирование, а про дизайн. Не нормальный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roboto хорошо тут подходит имхо
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Pridi